# How can the scaling dimension of a scalar field be $1$ in a $1d$ CFT?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, conformal-field-theory, dimensional-analysis, action, scaling

In a one-dimensional scalar field theory, the kinetic term of the action takes the following form:

$$S_\text{kin} = \int_\mathbb{R} dt\, \frac{1}{2} \dot{\varphi}(t) \dot{\varphi}(t)\,, \tag{1}$$

with $\dot{\varphi} = \partial_t \varphi$. This implies that the fields must have mass dimension $[\varphi]_M = -1/2$ for the action to be dimensionless.

Now there are $1d$ conformal theories, for example [line-defect CFTs](https://arxiv.org/abs/2107.08510), which have fundamental fields with *scaling* dimension $\Delta = 1$ in order to ensure that the theory is unitary. Can we write a kinetic term for these fundamental fields? How would that work, considering the kinetic term discussed above?

Comment: The same way a scaling dimension of a scalar field can be 0.5181489 in a 3d CFT. Scaling dimensions just are what they are and referring to the local operators that have them as "fundamental fields" is a mistake.

Comment: @ConnorBehan I see. So if I understand correctly, there exists some action with kinetic term $(1)$ for the defect $1d$ CFT, but the local operators may be defined differently, is that right?

Comment: CFT on a line defect is not a true 1d theory, so you want to somehow just write an 1d action for such line defect CFT it can not be a local kinetic term like your eq (1).